# How to rename filed in Clickhouse if it ordering key?

Tags: clickhouse

Table was created with `order by` expression and with field name that i need to rename. Is it possible? And here i mean renaming in place without table recreation and data transferring, and data lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, renaming a column that is part of the primary key is not possible at this time. This restriction is documented [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/column#rename-column). Likewise, it is not possible to remove a column in the primary key and to re-add it with a different name (or modify the primary key otherwise ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/147)).

Comment: Thank for fast reaction!